# Android Shape does not work on LG devices

Tags: android

I have this drawable as xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp" android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:topRightRadius="5dp" />
    <solid android:color="#000000" />
   <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#ffffff"/>
    <gradient android:startColor="#00000000" android:endColor="#00000000"
        android:angle="270" />      
</shape>
```

And I put this drawable on LinearLayout

```
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/llTime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/back_rounded"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="2dp">
```

Everything works fine. Except on some LG devices running their stock ROM. The shape should be transparent but on LG, the shape is filled with white block color.

What is wrong? And what is alternative solution?

Thanks

Comment: Hello, have you found the solution yet? I also have this problem, but with EVERYTHING that has a big background!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `<solid>` from:

```
<solid android:color="#000000" />
```

to:

```
<solid android:color="#00000000" />
```

(Set alpha value on the solid color)

Tested on LG Optimus LTE 2.